# Heegaard diagrams of prime 3-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, classification

Are there some known results which give a classification of closed prime 3-manifolds up to their Heegaard diagrams? (That is, providing a collection of Heegaard diagrams which exhausts all prime manifolds.)

Thanks.

Comment: There's a recent paper on this topic: http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.05945